# Google Analytics PHP API : goals not found

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client

In my company we decided to use Google Analytics to get some intersting metrics about visitors, entrance channels etc ...

I created a goal which is "triggered" when a visitor submit the contact form, everything work perfectly well and I even created a segment to preview the difference between people who use the form and the others.

Using the PHP API, i have my own dashboard table giving me some details about each session, one by one, with :

- every visited URL
- date & time
- if come from Adwords, then the keywords

Below a screenshot from my dashboard, with a visitor who went to my website thought the homepage (first row), then submit the contact form (second row).

[My own datas table from GA PHP API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BZO5.png)

**But.. i do not manage to link those datas with my goal !**
I tried metrics like :

- ga:goal1start
- ga:goal1Completions
- ga:goal1Value
- ga:goal1ConversationRate

(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

Whatever the metric I test (last column in my screnshot), the metric = 0 but I see completed goals in my Google Analytics dashboard for some of those sessions.

Is there something wrong ?
Thanks for your help ;)

EDIT 01/10 - Below is my PHP code :

```
$optParams = array(
      'dimensions' => 'ga:dimension3, ga:pagePath, ga:date, ga:adMatchedQuery, ga:hour',
      'sort' => '-ga:date, -ga:hour',
      //'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
      'max-results' => '99999');

   return $analytics->data_ga->get(
       'ga:' . $profileId,
       '30daysAgo',
       'today',
       'ga:pageviews, ga:goal2Completions ',
       $optParams);
```

And this is one row from the result :

```
array(7) {
[0]=>
string(12) "John Cena" // ga:dimension3
[1]=>
string(32) "/financial-expertise.php" // ga:pagePath
[2]=>
string(8) "20170110" // ga:date
[3]=>
string(9) "(not set)" // ga:adMatchedQuery
[4]=>
string(2) "12" // ga:hour
[5]=>
string(1) "1" // ga:pageviews
[6]=>
string(1) "0" // ga:goal2Completions ??
```

}

As you would see, the key "6" is related to the "ga:goal2Completions" metrics and in the above array, I guess it should be at least "1" ?

Comment: have you tested the query https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/ ? sounds like there is no data for that time.   please show us the code you are using to insert the goals as well as the php code you are using to extract it.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, yes i used the Query Explorer in order to test. Datas are well registered, i have my goal (Real name is "Goal2") which have been trigerred twice (on January 06th). Here is the config i use to generate my homemade dashboard : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/201007goal.png

Comment: Does someone have any idea ? I do not manage to link goals and pageviews, althought I get all the other datas OK. Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to supply us with a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve we can not help if we cant see what you are doing.

Comment: Dear DalmTo, I apologize. My original post is now completed with code snippet and test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK after hours of research .. no solution. So I have edited my goal to be equal to an event and then change my report to extract event. That works. Thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

for the php code 
can you try this one and tell me if its work or not ==>

```
        $optParams = array(
                    'dimensions' => 'ga:dimension3, ga:pagePath, ga:date, ga:adMatchedQuery, ga:hour',
                    'sort' => '-ga:date, -ga:hour',
                    //'filters' => 'ga:medium==organic',
        $metrics =  'ga:pageviews, ga:goal2Completions';  
        $from    =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of -1 month"));
        $to      =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime("today"));

  try {

        $campaigns = $service->data_ga->get( 'ga:' . $profileId,
                                            $from,
                                            $to ,
                                            $metrics,
                                            $optParams);

    } catch (\Google_Exception $e) {

        $message = sprintf("<h3>Oups !</h3>
                            <p>Request to  analytics failed.
                            Google error message was :</p>
                            <p><q>%s</q></p>", htmlspecialchars( $e->getMessage() ));
```

you need to { print_r }  $compaigns  and see the results

Comment: Hi Tony, still the same problem happening with your code :( Row number 6 (which is the ga:goal2Completions value) is always equal to 0 for each result ! Example : this particular row below has trigerred my goal one week ago :   [11]=>
    array(7) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "My custom dimension here"
      [1]=>
      string(12) "/contact.php"
      [2]=>
      string(8) "20170106"
      [3]=>
      string(17) "The adwords keyword here"
      [4]=>
      string(2) "16"
      [5]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [6]=>
      string(1) "0"
    }

Comment: When I look in my custom report, in Google Analytics : http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/497548aaa.png

Comment: in the google spreadsheet there is a addon "google analytics" its help you to see if the dimensions and the metrics is ok so you need to try it and if its ok so the code is wrong and will see .
this is a photo of the [addon](http://prnt.sc/dv5omv)